# Eigenvectors of a Symmetric Endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

> Prove that there isn't any symmetric endomorphism $f$ of $\mathbb R^3$ such that $e_1=(1,0,1)$ and $e_2=(1,1,1)$ are eigenvectors of $f$.

I don't know how to do it, any hint?

Comment: You can probably do it by contradiction and by considering the [Jordan canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) of $f$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prove it, because it's false.

Eigenvectors relative to distinct eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix are orthogonal, and $e_1$ is not orthogonal to $e_2$. But the two vectors could be relative to the same eigenvalue.

Indeed, there are several symmetric matrices with this property, for instance
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$